# Opening a URL in current window by using window.open in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, master-page, wiki-pages

I have a question about opening a URL in current window by using **window.open**. 
It is a master-page in SharePoint 2013

The condition is :

If current window is the site AAA, user opens the site BBB in this current window.

If current window is not the site AAA, user opens the site BBB in a new window.

The line `window.open("http://siteBBB","_blank");` works

but the line `window.open("http://siteBBB","_self");` does not work. It always the same page after the script running

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("http://siteAAA") > -1)
{       

    window.open("http://siteBBB","_self");

    } else 
    {window.open("http://siteBBB","_blank");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("http://siteAAA") > -1) {            
    window.location.href = "http://siteBBB";
} else {
    window.open("http://siteBBB","_blank");
}
```

Comment: I tried this, the same result like window.open. I added a alert after window.open(), the alert displays when script running, and the page refresh. But always the same page, it does not change

Comment: Maybe I should  force a script re-execute for **window.open**?

Comment: Which browser you are testing with? Also try `window.location.assign("http://siteBBB");` and `window.location.replace("http://siteBBB")`